# calculate the session duration in terms of values of another column in python

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time

In my data frame I have these two columns "event" and "date" I want to calculate session duration . when event is "create" session started and when the event is "delete" the session is ended.
How to go about this problem??

```
event      date

Create     2019-11-20 12:00:04

delete     2019-11-20 12:00:09

create     2019-11-20 18:07:10

create     2019-11-20 18:10:12

delete     2019-11-20 18:13:12

delete     2019-11-20 18:14:20
```

Expected output is 
0:0:05
0:06:02
0:04:08
since three pairs of create and delete are there

I was thinking of pushing the elements into a stack when we encounter create and pop them when we encounter delete and thereby calculate the session duration.Dont know how to implement it.Can someone help?

Comment: have you demonstrated _any_ evidence of trying it out yourself?

Comment: Add expected output in your question